# Clip/Filter Raster serviced as WMS by geoserver

Tags: raster, geoserver

I have imageMoasic raster layer in GeoServer. I process geotiffs from my API into the GeoServer instance data directly and from there I create the raster layer. I access the raster layer as WMS. My problem is this: my geotiffs cover large polygon which can be 5-6 States but on the client side, I want to clip the raster to show the specific State for the specific client. For example, If my Chicago clients log in into my application I don't want them to see other parts of the big polygon but only Chicago. What are the options in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your best choice is to use a geometric [CQL_FILTER](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) parameter. CQL filters can use any of the available [filtering functions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#filter-function-reference) in GeoServer.

Here is a snippet from the documentation that achieves your goal, methinks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of using such things. Will give a try If it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are mistaken as to the nature of a WMS, it returns a **picture** of your data not a raster. As such it will always return a rectangular image so the only way you could "clip" the result would be to modify the layers that your client requests.

So you could split your input rasters in to the areas that you wish to server and add them to GeoServer as separate layers. Then your client in Chicago only requests the Chicago layer, while your New York client only requests the New York layer.

Alternatively, if all you are interested in is the viewer experience just start your client up already zoomed into the area of interest. This won't prevent the New York user zooming out and panning across to Chicago but they won't see Chicago to start.

Comment: Thanks. Is it not possible to do some filtering using SLD or anything to make some area transparent?